# Is there a term for cards that have the same name in the same set (like basic lands) but are different cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, terminology

It seems "reprints" is used for cards that are reprinted. But is there terminology for cards that have the same name but are in the same set?

For example if there are 3 or 4 different "Mountain" basic lands, in the same set, I don't think the term "reprint" quite correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term is **variant.** There are usually 3–4 variants of each basic land in a set. Promos offer an alternate art variant of the card. The term was also used to describe [the Unstable cards that had alternate functional variants](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Unstable#Variant_cards).